# Uniformly convergent subsequence of Equicontinuous R to R functions which are bounded in a point

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, bounded-variation

Suppose that $(f_n)$ is an equicontinuous sequence of functions $f_n : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $(f_n (0))$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Does there exist a subsequence that converges uniformly? Prove
or give a counter-example.

If we limit the functions to a closed interval $[a,b]$, by the following fact and $\mathbb{R}$ is chain-connected, And then by Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, the problem is solved.

> $M$ is chain connected if and only if pointwise boundedness
>   of an equicontinuous family at one point of $M$ implies pointwise
>   boundedness at every point of $M$.

But I still don't know the case of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

What if :

- $\mathbb{R}^m$ replaces $\mathbb{R}$ ?
- $\mathbb{N}$ replaces $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f_n(x):=\min\{|x|,n\}$. We have for all $x,y\in\mathbb N$ and each integer $n$ that 
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leqslant |x-y|,$$
hence $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly equi-continuous. Since $f_n(0)=0$, the all the conditions are fulfilled.

But if $m\neq n$, we have $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=|n-m|\geqslant 1$, hence no subsequence can converge uniformly on the real line.

Comment: What if R^m or N replaces R ?

Comment: For $\mathbb R^m$ it shouldn't be a problem: $|x|$ denotes the Euclidian norm. For $\mathbb N$, what do you mean by equi-continuous family?